# Yii: search by a HAS_MANY relation

Tags: yii

I have following tables

```
notice[id, type], 
property[id, type], 
property_value[id, notice_id, property_id, value].
```

Each notice has own properties specified by it's type. I need to make a filter by several properties simultaniously, and issue is how to specify which property shoud have a specified value?

```
class Notice extends CActiveRecord{

  /** @var array property_id=>value from $_GET*/
  public $searchParams= array();

  public function search() {

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    // $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->compare('t.type', $this->type);

    foreach ( $searchParams as $property_id => $value) {
      /// What should i write here?
      /// $criteria->compare('propertyValues.id', $id);
      /// $criteria->compare('propertyValues.value', $value);
    }
  }
}
```

Ps: Found  [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/428/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation/) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285681/yii-has-many-search)  but i need specify params...

Comment: $criteria->with = array('YOUR_TABLE' => array('alias' => 'nt'));
// it joins a table you have specified

Comment: zazu, yes you are right, forgot to write it, but that isn't the point:
for example: i have an appartment to search on 3rd floor and with 4 rooms, both of this parameters stored in one column...

Comment: Can you explain/show me the relations() at each's model class? It's easy if tou have the correct relations()

Comment: @Skatox sorry, for late answer, but i found my issue is around EAV model...There is one relation in Notice model ('propertyValues' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'propertyValue', 'notice_id'))  and one in PropertyValue ('property' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Property', 'property_id'))

Answer (score 0):

As i found this issue is around a classic EAV model (Entity–attribute–value). So for temporary (but no finest) solution i join value's table multiply times for every parameter:

```
 public function search() {    
   foreach ($properties as $id => $value) {
     $joinAlias = 'p_' . $property->id;
     $join = "\nLEFT JOIN property_value as $joinAlias ON t.id= {$joinAlias}.notice_id AND {$joinAlias}.property_id='{$property_id}'  ";
     $criteria->compare("{$joinAlias}.value", $value);
     $criteria->join .= $join;
   }
 }
```